# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated?

Tags: c, realloc

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I get stuck here for a while.

Let's say `freq_tostring()` converts a word frequency `freq` into string, and `freq_intostream()` appends that string to the end of a stream.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct {
    char *word; // null-terminated
    int freq;
} freq;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
void new_freq(freq *fq, const char *word, const int freq) {
    fq->word = (char *)malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 for null-terminator
    strcpy(fq->word, word);
    fq->freq = freq;
}

/**
 * Free memory
 */
void dispose_freq(void *fq) {
    freq *p = (freq *)fq;
    free(p->word);
    p->word = NULL;
}

/**
 * snprintf() will terminate the string with a null character, unless buf_size is zero.
 */
char *freq_tostring(freq *fq) {
    size_t wordlen = strlen(fq->word);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(wordlen + 16); // maximum integer has 10 digits
    snprintf(buffer, wordlen + 16, "[%s, %d]\n", fq->word, fq->freq);
    return buffer;
}

/**
 * Append the string of freq to the end of stream.
 */
void freq_intostream(void *elem, void *stream) {
    freq *fq = (freq *)elem;
    char *str = *(char **)stream;
    size_t strsize = strlen(str);
    // printf("Stream = \"%s\", length = %lu\n", str, strsize);
    char *word = freq_tostring(fq);
    size_t wordsize = strlen(word);
    // printf("Element = \"%s\"%lu\n", word, wordsize);
    char *temp = (char *)realloc(str, strsize + wordsize + 1);
    strcpy(temp + strsize, word);
    temp[strsize + wordsize] = '\0';
    // printf("After strcpy(): \"%s\"\n", temp);
    str = temp;
    free(word);
}


int main(void) {
    freq apple, banana, kiwi;
    new_freq(&apple, "apple", 3);
    new_freq(&banana, "banana", 2);
    new_freq(&kiwi, "kiwi", 5);

    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(1);
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    freq_intostream(&apple, &buffer);
    freq_intostream(&banana, &buffer);
    freq_intostream(&kiwi, &buffer);

    assert(strlen(buffer) == 33); 
    assert(strcmp(buffer, "[apple, 3]\n[banana, 2]\n[kiwi, 5]\n") == 0);

    dispose_freq(&apple);
    dispose_freq(&banana);
    dispose_freq(&kiwi);
    free(buffer);
}
```

The weird thing is, when I run 10 times, it gives me about 9 `pointer being realloc'd was not allocated`, but maybe in 1~2 cases, everything is ok.

If I comment out the `printf()`, it shows that before appending the third element `kiwi`, the stream is empty, and that could be why realloc is failed. But I'm sure that I pass a pointer of `char * stream` to the `freq_intostream()` function, which is a `char **` for sure. I can't find out what's the problem, anyone can help?

Comment: `str = temp` does not copy the contents of the buffer pointed to by `temp` into the buffer pointed to by `str`. It just sets the pointer `str` to the same address as `temp`. Perhaps you wanted `strcpy(str, temp)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done the equivalent of `i = j; i = 3;` when you wanted `j = 3;`. Obviously, these don't do the same thing. Have a close look at the marked line in this funciton:

```
/**
 * Append the string of freq to the end of stream.
 */
void freq_intostream(void *elem, void *stream) {
    freq *fq = (freq *)elem;
    char *str = *(char **)stream;
    size_t strsize = strlen(str);
    // printf("Stream = \"%s\", length = %lu\n", str, strsize);
    char *word = freq_tostring(fq);
    size_t wordsize = strlen(word);
    // printf("Element = \"%s\"%lu\n", word, wordsize);
    char *temp = (char *)realloc(str, strsize + wordsize + 1);
    strcpy(temp + strsize, word);
    temp[strsize + wordsize] = '\0';
    // printf("After strcpy(): \"%s\"\n", temp);
    str = temp; // OOPS!!
    free(word);
}
```

You change the value of `str`, but `str` is a local to this function and its value is thrown away as soon as the function ends.

You wanted: `*(char**)stream = temp;` to change the value the caller passed you a pointer to.

This code would be much simpler if you get rid of all the casts. If `elem` were of type `char **`, you could just do `*elem = temp;` and the code would be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @David Schwartz. I tested with `*(char **)stream = temp`, it works. But I'm still a little bit confused, if `str` in stack is lost, why in 10% of the case, the code can pass the test?

Comment: And the test always fails at the third element "kiwi", that means for the first two element "apple“ and "banana" it works correctly with the wrong code `str = temp`. That sounds strange?

Comment: Does it means for the first two element, `realloc` just enlarge the original memory space, and for the third element it try to create a new memory space, and in that case my `str = temp` will fail. Am I right?

Comment: @shen That's a possible theory. The `realloc` function doesn't always change the pointer and, even if it does, it still might just happen to work fine when you overrun the buffer. The consequences of UB can depend on weird platform quirks.